# How to catch all the links, read their attributes and prevent them from executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to catch all the `.click()` events that occurs on links on my page. Also, I want to read attributes of a link currently clicked. As far I have this, but there is a problem with it:

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myPage").load("/ #myPage");
});
```

First of all, this code works only one out of two times - first time I click on a link, this code doesn't work, second click, this code works, third click, doesn't, etc. Why is that? Also, how can I read attributes of a link? I need to read src and class attributes.

**Edit:** What I need to do, is to catch whenever someone clicks on a link, stop that from happening, read href and class attributes of a link, and then proceed with loading the page (but not reloading, just replacing #myPage)

**Edit2:** Okay, so now the only problem is, why is it working one out of two times for me? When I load the page, then click a link, jquery works fine, but after second click, it is not hitting my `$("a").click()` event!

**Solution:** I fixed my problem by replacing .click() with .live() - now works every time. ;)

Comment: links does not have src attribute

Comment: Are these `<a>` elements placed in `#myPage` block?

Comment: For the attributes of link clicked, access the element via `$(this).attr();`

Comment: @Huangism: sorry, i meant href.

Comment: @VisioN: Yes and no... Why does that matter?

Comment: If the `<a>`s are added dynamically, make sure to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: try your original code without the load part and to get attribute it's just $(this).attr('href')

Comment: @Huangism: I will edit my post to explain what I need to do. :)

Comment: @ojek That matters if you rewrite these `<a>` elements with bound events.

Comment: @VisioN: I have my javascript in a file that is not being reloaded, while `<a>` are reloaded. What youre telling me is, that it might work once out of two times, because of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first part: `How can I prevent link click:`

just return false from your click event

```
$("a").click(function(e) { return false; });
```

Second part: `how can I read attribute of a link`

```
   $("a").click(function(){
              var href= $(this).attr('href');
              alert(href);
              return false;
      });
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6kFD/)

Comment: How is your `e.preventDefault` different from the question?

Comment: But I need to read all the attributes of a link currently clicked.

Comment: Okay, I have used your code and it is fine, but still, it works only once out of two times. Why would it be?

Comment: did you see the fiddle? everything works, just one line is missing there `$("#myPage").load("/ #myPage");`.it is the culprit

Comment: @ManishMishra: Well, not really. When I put a breakpoint on my `$("a").click()` event, it is being hit for the first time, but not for the second...

Comment: so that means, now the click event is no longer bound to the anchors i.e. when you reload the content through .load, anchor click event  bind data is lost. try wrapping this $('#a").click.. code in a function, call it when you click and call it after you perform .load.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").on('click', function(e) {

    // stop click event
    e.preventDefault();

    // get href attribute of currently clicked item
    var hrefAttr = $(this).attr('href');

    // get class attribute
    var classAttr = $(this).attr('class');

    // do loading here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>According to http://api.jquery.com/click/ the click() handler is **potentially** fired twice.</strike> Once for mousedown and once for mouseup. Perhaps you can utilize $.on('mouseup', function(e) { }); instead?

For attributes you can use:

```
$('a').attr('src');
```

In summary:

```
$("a").on('mouseup', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $("#myPage").load("/#myPage");
});
```

Comment: `click` event fires only once.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I could've swore I had issues in the past with it firing twice using click(), but my jsfiddle testing is proving otherwise.